# Bootstrap table with fixed header and no scroll on body

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, css, html-table

I'm trying to create a table component in a custom way I man the table `<thead>` to be fixed and the `<tbody>` to be scrollable without having a body scroll.

1. The thing is I don't know how to set a height for the `div.content-table` that is keeping the table in order to have all the time same height size but not bigger than screen size so I cannot add a px or other kind of fixed size.
2. I don't know why position fixed is not working for `<thead>` :|

**[fiddle example:](https://jsfiddle.net/nwa7hg2L/)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### 1. not bigger than screen size

You can use `vw`,`vh` unit for that.

```
1vh = 1% * screenHeight
1vw = 1% * screenWidth
```

So in your case

```
max-height = calc(100vh - 200px);
max-width = 100vw;
```

### 2. why position fixed not work

if you use

```
thead{
  position:fixed;
}
```

`thead` will work separately from `tbody`, I think css calculate separately on `position:fixed` element.

MORE INFO
[table header fixed example](https://codepen.io/tjvantoll/pen/JEKIu)

Comment: the thing is I have used 100vh for the container but I forgot to add the calc with - height of header. I think your suggestion will work :)

Comment: to make your table header fixed, please see this link, it will help you. https://codepen.io/tjvantoll/pen/JEKIu

Comment: that is a good example but I have discovered a very easy method that is working like charm : table thead tr{
    display:block;
}

table th,table td{
    width:100px;
}

table  tbody{
  display:block;
  height:200px;
  overflow:auto;
}

Comment: happy to hear that

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

[**jquery-1.12.4.js**](https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js) ,

[**jquery.dataTables.min.js**](https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js)

& [**jquery.dataTables.min.css**](https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css)

Update [`JSFiddle`](https://jsfiddle.net/nwa7hg2L/1/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('#example').DataTable();

})
```

```css
.header {
  align-items: center;
  background: orange none repeat scroll 0 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}
.content{
  padding-top: 140px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="header">
  <h3 class="heading">
We have a heading here !
</h3>
  <p class="small">And this is a text</p>
</div>

<div class="content">
  <div class="table-responsive">
    <table id="example" class="table table-bordered">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>#</th>
          <th>Table heading</th>
          <th>Table heading</th>
          <th>Table heading</th>
          <th>Table heading</th>
          <th>Table heading</th>
          <th>Table heading</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">1</th>
          <td>Table cell</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">2</th>
          <td>Table cell</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">3</th>
          <td>Table cell</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">4</th>
          <td>Table cell</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">5</th>
          <td>Table cell</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">6</th>
          <td>Table cell</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">7</th>
          <td>Table cell</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">8</th>
          <td>Table cell</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">9</th>
          <td>Table cell</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">10</th>
          <td>Table cell</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">11</th>
          <td>Table cell</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">12</th>
          <td>Table cell</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">13</th>
          <td>Table cell</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">14</th>
          <td>Table cell</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">15</th>
          <td>Table cell</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">16</th>
          <td>Table cell</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">17</th>
          <td>Table cell</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">18</th>
          <td>Table cell</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I am using angular, I cannot add jQuery.